# curl and file_get_contents not work after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm trying to retrieve user's city info by using the coordinates. There is a javascript function that takes latitude/longitude and sends it across to a php file with ajax:

**Javascript function**

```
if (navigator.geolocation) { //Checks if browser supports geolocation
        var Clatitude = "no";
        var Clongitude;

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                Clatitude = position.coords.latitude;
                Clongitude = position.coords.longitude;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../wp-content/themes/Avada-child/test_BLZ.php",
                    data: {'latitudine': Clatitude,'longitudine': Clongitude},
                    success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    },
                    dataType: "JSON"
                });
            },
            function(error) {

                 alert(error.message);
                 }, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 5000
            });
    }
```

**Server side script written in PHP**

```
<?php

$latitudine = $_POST['latitudine'];
$longitudine = $_POST['longitudine'];
$geolocation = $latitudine.','.$longitudine;
$request = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$geolocation.'&sensor=false'; 
$file_contents = url_get_contents($request);
echo ($file_contents);

function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
?>
```

The problem is that the response is not displayed in my console. I tried to ge the response with `file_get_contents` and still was not able to retrieve the response

Except for this, the rest of the code works fine. In fact as soon as I remove `curl's` stuff or `file_get_contents` from the php file, the rest of the code functions smoothly. I even managed to retrieve a (fake) response in ajax success function.

Can someone help? Thanks ;)

---edit 
my curl execution time is very long, i run the same code on another server and these are the differences:

**server with long curl execution time**

```
{
   "url": "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=45.644843,8.9986268&sensor=false",
   "content_type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
   "http_code": 200,
   "header_size": 377,
   "request_size": 119,
   "filetime": -1,
   "ssl_verify_result": 0,
   "redirect_count": 0,
   "total_time": 127.26954,
   "namelookup_time": 0.001964,
   "connect_time": 127.23926,
   "pretransfer_time": 127.239265,
   "size_upload": 0,
   "size_download": 11729,
   "speed_download": 92,
   "speed_upload": 0,
   "download_content_length": -1,
   "upload_content_length": 0,
   "starttransfer_time": 127.269424,
   "redirect_time": 0,
   "certinfo": []
   "request_header":"GET \/maps\/api\/geocode\/json?latlng=45.644843,8.9986268&sensor=false HTTP\/1.1\r\nHost: maps.googleapis.com\r\nAccept: *\/*\r\n\r\n"
}
```

**server with short curl execution time**

```
{
   "url": "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=45.644843,8.9986268&sensor=false",
   "content_type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
   "http_code": 200,
   "header_size": 377,
   "request_size": 119,
   "filetime": -1,
   "ssl_verify_result": 0,
   "redirect_count": 0,
   "total_time": 0.116182,
   "namelookup_time": 0.012194,
   "connect_time": 0.027452,
   "pretransfer_time": 0.027473,
   "size_upload": 0,
   "size_download": 11729,
   "speed_download": 100953,
   "speed_upload": 0,
   "download_content_length": -1,
   "upload_content_length": 0,
   "starttransfer_time": 0.114101,
   "redirect_time": 0,
   "redirect_url": "",
   "primary_ip": "172.217.**.**",
   "certinfo": [],
   "primary_port": 80,
   "local_ip": "192.168.**.**",
   "local_port": 51393
   "request_header":"GET \/maps\/api\/geocode\/json?latlng=45.644843,8.9986268&sensor=false HTTP\/1.1\r\nHost: maps.googleapis.com\r\nAccept: *\/*\r\n\r\n"
}
```

What is the matter with my server? I notice that in the first case there aren't ip references!

Comment: run your php file directly from browser, change $_POST['latitudine'] and $_POST['longitudine'] to static values and check what response google through

Comment: wow! i discover that the execution time of the curl is > 130 sec!! Why??

Comment: check request headers from both server does it contain any "Accept-Encoding" header . if yes what are the values?

Comment: edit my question, I hope I understood what you mean. the request headers are the same..

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');  set this in your function and check if it resolves

Comment: nothing changed :/

Answer (score -1):

As your response from server is not in in form of `JSON`, so you should not set `dataType:"JSON"` from `AJAX` call.

Please comment it out from `AJAX` call.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../wp-content/themes/Avada-child/test_BLZ.php",
   data: {'latitudine': Clatitude,'longitudine': Clongitude},
   success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   },
   //dataType: "JSON"     <-- COMMENT this out
});
```

**OR**
Another option is that you should send `JSON` encoded response from server.

```
$file_contents = url_get_contents($request);
echo (json_encode($file_contents));
```